# A 'return' expression required in a function with a block body despite inlined lambda which has the return

Tags: kotlin, lambda, inline

I'm trying to create an inlined try-catch helper function but running into a compilation error due to the `return` statement occurring within the inlined lambda. Below is some code demonstrating the same issue

```kotlin
fun isStringEmpty(myString: String): Boolean {
    stringOpHelper { 
        return myString.length == 0
    }
}
inline fun <T> stringOpHelper(fn: () -> T) {
    println("performing string operation")
    fn()
}
```

This will compile with the desired effect if a return is added after the inlined function call or an exception is thrown, but that code should be unreachable. Eg:

```kotlin
fun isStringEmpty(myString: String): Boolean {
    stringOpHelper { 
        return myString.length == 0
    }
    TODO("this is actually unreachable")
}
inline fun <T> stringOpHelper(fn: () -> T) {
    println("performing string operation")
    fn()
}
```

My expectation was that the compiler would see that `stringOpHelper` always calls `fn()` and the `fn` in `isStringEmpty` always returns, so the inlined `stringOpHelper` call always returns.

Is it possible to define the inline helper function in a way that avoids the need for the unreachable exception / return in the calling function? Otherwise, what's the reason for why this isn't possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is mechanism for such purposes called [*contracts*](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew13.html#contracts), but this feature is experimental and its usage must be marked with `@ExperimentalContracts` or `@OptIn(ExperimentalContracts::class)`

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalContracts::class)
inline fun <T> stringOpHelper(fn: () -> T) {
    contract {
        callsInPlace(fn, kotlin.contracts.InvocationKind.EXACTLY_ONCE)
    }
    println("performing string operation")
    fn()
}
```

Comment: Ah thank you for sharing this. Too bad it's experimental still